# Get row separately for each category - django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)


class Website(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='website_category')
    ...
```

Since each website can have multiple categories so I want to fetch each website multiple times for each category.

For example:

website 1 has categories: Category 1, Category 2
website 2 has categories: Category 2, Category 3

Required Output:

| Website | Category |
| --- | --- |
| website 1 | category 1 |
| website 1 | category 2 |
| website 2 | category 2 |
| website 2 | category 3 |

I'm relatively new to Django ORM and unable to construct a query to fetch the desired results, so any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: did you try to do `Website.category.through.objects.all()`?

Comment: Perfect! Many Thanks @JameelHamdan
How does this "through" work btw?

Comment: the models.ManyToManyField creates a join table, the .through just accesses it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the created join table through this code

```
Website.category.through.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the category under website,

```
web1 = Website.objects.get(id='your_id')
web1.category.all()
```

To get all the website under category,

```
cat1 = Category.objects.get(id='your_id')
cat1.website_set.all()
```

Comment: I'm willing to fetch the results with 1 query.

As approach of getting websites for each category will require 2 loops to show the results

Comment: what result you're expecting.

Comment: Result as stated in the question. 
"Website.category.through.objects.all()" did the job!